# Check if pg_upgrade ran successfully

Tags: postgresql, migration

Is there a way to query the dB to know if `pg_upgrade` ran successfully and migrated the data? I want to know if a database is fresh post-installation or the data from the previous version has been migrated. The previous dB can be empty as well.

Comment: What operating system?  Please [edit] your question to include the appropriate [tag].

Comment: @MarkStewart operating system is Win10.

Answer (score 0):

When `pg_upgraded` completed successfully (return code 0), it upgraded the database.

Comment: It doesn't return a return code but a text log, somewhere in it `Ùpgrade Completed` is written.

Comment: All commands have a return code. In `bash`, for example, the return code of the last statement is stored in the `$?` variable.

Comment: Processes have a return code, not PowerShell runspaces. Also, there can be a return code 0 even when the data is not migrated, for instance when the service is still running. That is why I would want to query the dB to know if pg_upgrade ran successfully.

Comment: `pg_upgrade` is a command, not a Powershell runspace (whatever that is). There cannot be a return code before the command is done. I guess you'll have to figure out how to run a command with that Powershell and how to get at the return code.

Comment: `pg_upgrade` will give a return code 0, even when it fails to migrate data. E.x. when the windows service is still running. My question isn't directly about running pg_upgrade but knowing if a postgres dB is empty or does it contain some data.

Comment: That is not true. If the source cluster is running, `pg_upgrade` will exit with return code 1. I just tried it.